# How to get <a href= value inside div with class name only?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, href

I am trying to get value of href inside a div with class name(class="visible-xs"). I tried this code and it gets all the href outside div as well which I don't want.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($code2);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
{

 echo $node->getAttribute("href")."\n";
}
```

Then i tried following but it gives me error(Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementsByClassName() in..):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($code2);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByClassName('visible-xs') as $bigDiv) {

   echo $bigDiv->getAttribute("href")."\n";
}
```

could any one help me fix the above error and only get the value of href inside div with class name visible-xs ?Thanks in advance.

sample data:

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in itemContent">
<td class="ng-binding" style="word-wrap: break-word;">test/folder/1.mp4
<div class="visible-xs" style="padding-top: 10px;">
<!-- ngIf: item.isViewable --> class="btn btn-default ng-scope" ng-click="$root.openView(item);">View</a><!-- end ngIf: item.isViewable -->
<a href="https://somesite.com/test/1.mp4" class="btn btn-default" ng-href="https://somesite.com/test/1.mp4" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="item.upload()" target="_blank">Upload</a>
</div>
</td>
<!-- ngIf: hasViewables --><td class="text-right hidden-xs ng-scope" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 60px;" ng-if="hasViewables">
<!-- ngIf: item.isViewable -->class="btn btn-default ng-scope" ng-click="$root.openView(item);">View</a><!-- end ngIf: item.isViewable -->
</td><!-- end ngIf: hasViewables -->
<td class="text-right hidden-xs" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 250px;">
<a href="https://somesite.com/test/1.mp4" class="btn btn-default" ng-href="https://somesite.com/test/1.mp4" target="_blank">Download</a>
javascript:void(0);" ng-click="item.upload()" target="_blank">Upload</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.Can you show me an example of how to use xpath for this purpose ?

Comment: I tried following but no data :$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($code2);

$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[class="visible-xs"]//a[@href]') as $link) {

       echo  $link->getAttribute('href');

    }

Comment: The div class name is visible-xs and the <a href class name inside div is btn btn-default. I want to get https://somesite.com/test/1.mp4 once not multiple times

Comment: I updated the sample data in first post. Unfortunately the data is presented like that .The data comes from remote website and i have no control over how it presents data ! I want to get href value of this line only  <a href="https://somesite.com/test/1.mp4" class="btn btn-default" ng-href="https://somesite.com/test/1.mp4" target="_blank">Download</a>
javascript:void(0);" ng-click="item.upload()" target="_blank">Upload</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `getElementsByClassName` function. Iterate over your divs, check the class, if matched pull the links inside and output the `href`s you want (or break if you want to stop after the first match).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div) {
     if($div->getattribute('class') == 'visible-xs') {
          foreach($div->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
               echo $link->getattribute('href');
          }
     }
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/698484

Example with the `break`, https://eval.in/698488.

Comment: Many thanks .That demo helped me alot but how i can ignore href value of <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="item.upload()" target="_blank">Upload</a> ? (my mistake i forget to correct the sample data)

Comment: Sure you could use `strpos` or `preg_match` to block `href`s that are `javascript`. Do it the same way I checked for the class.